# Meaning of {0}\{1} in C#

Tags: c#

What is the meaning of `{0}\{1}` in c#, it returns some string, but in which format and what kind of string?

Comment: These are likely the zero indexed format placeholders passed to [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

Comment: `{0}\{1}` is invalid C#. `@"{0}\{1}"` is a string literal containing seven characters, namely `'{'`, `'0'`, `'}'`, etc. No more than that. What the answers guess but what you *really* should have stated is that your question is about using that as a format string with `string.Format`. In this case, it happened to be easy enough to guess, but for other questions probably not so, meaning other questions asked this way are unlikely to get useful answers.

Comment: Technically, "{0}\{1}" means **absolutely nothing** in C#. It does, however, have meaning when *part of a format string*, in a few methods like `string.Format`, `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` and `DataContact.ExecuteQuery`

Comment: it is used in string.Format method

Comment: `string.Format` is not "C#" - that is the framework / BCL. Basically, what hvd said.

Comment: String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args); . In 3rd argument there is {0}\{1}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that it is expecting parameters to be replaced in string. something like.

```
string.Format("{0}{1}","parameter1","parameter2");
```

You may see: [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

> A composite format string and object list are used as arguments of
>   methods that support the composite formatting feature. A composite
>   format string consists of zero or more runs of fixed text intermixed
>   with one or more format items. The fixed text is any string that you
>   choose, and each format item corresponds to an object or boxed
>   structure in the list. The composite formatting feature returns a new
>   result string where each format item is replaced by the string
>   representation of the corresponding object in the list.

Comment: And the numbers represent the index of the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

These are the arguments/params usually used in the string format function:

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17, 9, 30, 0); 
string city = "Chicago";
int temp = -16;
string output = String.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.",
                              dat, city, temp);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output: 
//    At 1/17/2012 9:30:00 AM in Chicago, the temperature was -16 degrees.
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

They are format specifier, used with `string.Format` or `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` and similar functions.

See [the manual for string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) for a detailed explanation.